# Getting latest version of openssl in bash

Tags: bash, openssl

I am trying to get latest version of openssl in `1.0.2 series` in bash.Essentially i want to get the download link of the latest version of curl available and the latest version in bash.The problem is that openssl doesn't use the `latest` tag in their github releases.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programing question, but rather about how to install softwares on a linux distro

Comment: @Aserre i know how to install software mate....but hard coding version value in code is inefficient since i have to modify it each time a new version comes out.

Comment: Isn't the latest version always on the `master` branch ? you could parse the output of `git remote -v update` to make sure you are up to date

Comment: There are plenty of package managers available; don't try to implement your own in `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the latest OpenSSL archive you could use one of the OpenSSL FTP mirrors. Here is a sample bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# An ftp mirror, see here https://www.openssl.org/source/mirror.html
mirror_url='ftp://gd.tuwien.ac.at/infosys/security/openssl/'

# Last modified date of source directory
last_modified=$(curl -s $mirror_url | awk '/source/{print $6,$7,$8}')

# OpenSSL archive with same modification Date as source dir
latest_archive=$(curl -s "$mirror_url"source/ | grep "$last_modified.*tar.gz$"|awk '{print $NF}')

# URL of latest release
latest_release=$mirror_url"source/"$latest_archive

# Download latest release
curl -sO "$latest_release"
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.Your solution is working fine but i am wondering that sometimes it may return a fips version of openssl if it was release earlier.Can you modify your code to exclude the fips version of openssl just to be on the safe side

Comment: You could filter out the fips string by being more specific with grep, try something like this: `grep "$last_modified.*openssl-[0-9].*tar.gz$"`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get latest version of openssl in 1.0.2 series in bash ...

As far as I know, Bash does not use OpenSSL. It also does not have a download tool or manager built-in, so you will need to use an external command like `curl` or `wget`.

To perform the download, you need to visit the [OpenSSL download](http://www.openssl.org/source/) page. Then, its as simple as:

```
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz
--2016-11-25 10:00:22--  https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz
Resolving www.openssl.org (www.openssl.org)... 23.6.16.135, ...
Connecting to www.openssl.org (www.openssl.org)|23.6.16.135|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307912 (5.1M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz’

openssl-1.0.2j.tar. 100%[===================>]   5.06M  6.67MB/s    in 0.8s    

2016-11-25 10:00:23 (6.67 MB/s) - ‘openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz’ saved [5307912/5307912]

$ tar xzf openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz 
$
```

---

You can script it with something like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VERSIONS=(z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a)
for v in ${VERSIONS[@]};
do
    if [[ $(wget -S --spider https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2$v.tar.gz 2>&1 | grep 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') ]];
    then
        if [[ ! $(wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2$v.tar.gz &>/dev/null) ]];
        then
            echo "Downloaded openssl-1.0.2$v.tar.gz"
        else
            echo "Failed to download openssl-1.0.2$v.tar.gz"
        fi

        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: i am interested only with the latest version here.Would extracting the url from https://www.openssl.org/source/ be a better solution